Not able to handle the Java launcher popup in chrome using selenium Java after upgrading the chrome to 128 version.can I get solution for this
Not able to handle the Java Web launcher popup in headless chrome after upgrading the chrome version to 128
We have tried to use to multiple options to disable the plugins in automation code or tried to handle Java web launcher in headless chrome..it's not working
